# how to check the dimension of each tensor when running a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, printing, tensorflow, shapes, dimension

I tried the `tf.Print` thing but it seems not printing anything.

Here are my codes, and I tried to `tf.Print` the dimension of the `reshape` tensor. How should I fix the code to print out the dimensions of reshape?

```
batch_size = 32
image_height = 480
image_width = 720
num_channels = 4
num_labels = 18

deep_graph = tf.Graph()
with deep_graph.as_default():

tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(x_valid, dtype = tf.float32_ref)
#tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(x_test, dtype = tf.float32_ref) 

tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, 
    shape = (batch_size, image_height, image_width, num_channels))

tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (batch_size, num_labels))

conv1_weight = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, num_channels, 32], 
                        stddev = 0.1, seed = 0))

conv1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([32]))

conv2_weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 32, 64], 
                            stddev = 0.1, seed = 0, dtype = tf.float32))

conv2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [64]))

fc1_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([image_height * image_width * 32 , 512], 
                        stddev = 0.1, seed = 0, dtype = tf.float32))

fc1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [512]))

fc2_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([512, 512], 
                        stddev = 0.1, seed = 0, dtype = tf.float32))

fc2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [512]))

fc3_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([512, num_labels], stddev = 0.1, seed = 0, dtype = tf.float32))

fc3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape = [num_labels]))

def model(data, train = False):
    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(data, conv1_weight, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')

    relu1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, conv1_biases))

    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, ksize = [1, 2, 2, 1], 
                            strides = [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = 'SAME')

    conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, conv2_weights, strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding = 'SAME')

    relu2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, conv2_biases))

    pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu2, ksize = [1, 2, 2, 1],
                            strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding = 'SAME')

    # Reshape the feature map cuboid into a 2D matrix to feed it to the
    # fully connected layers.
    pool_shape = pool2.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, [pool_shape[0], pool_shape[1] * pool_shape[2] * pool_shape[3]])
    reshape = tf.Print(reshape, [reshape], "reshape: ", summarize=10)
    # Fully connecte layers
    hidden_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, fc1_weights) + fc1_biases)
    # For training data, add 0.5 dropout. 
    if train:
        hidden_layer1 = tf.nn.dropout(hidden_layer1, 0.5, seed = 0)

    hidden_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden_layer1, fc2_weights) + fc2_biases)

    if train:
        hidden_layer2 = tf.nn.dropout(hidden_layer2, 0.5, seed = 0)

    return tf.matmul(hidden_layer2, fc3_weights) + fc3_biases

# Call the model() function to make train_prediction
train_prediction = model(tf_train_dataset, True)

# calculate loss by using train_prediction
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(train_prediction - tf_train_labels), 1))
# Add L2 regularization to loss
loss += 1e-7 * (tf.nn.l2_loss(fc1_weights) + tf.nn.l2_loss(fc1_biases) +
        tf.nn.l2_loss(fc2_weights) + tf.nn.l2_loss(fc2_biases) + 
        tf.nn.l2_loss(fc3_weights) + tf.nn.l2_loss(fc3_biases)) 

# Optimizer
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name = 'global_step',trainable = False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.001
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate,
                                            global_step,
                                            100000,
                                            0.96,
                                            staircase = True)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.95).minimize(loss, global_step = global_step)
```

Comment: You can look at the `reshape` value in your session along with its shape using `x.get_shape()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`print (reshape.get_shape().as_list())`

Which will print out the dimensions of your tensor as a list. If you don't have `as_list`, the output will look something like this: `TensorShape([Dimension(1), Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])`